# SSL_CLOSE_NOTIFY Not received by client when nginx proxy is used

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx proxy server as a reverse proxy and https load balancer.  Client connects to backend server through the reverse proxy in a load balanced environment. I have setup the correct https configuration (with ssl certificates and all) so that my ssl communication is going through proxy. The only problem I am facing is client don't get SSL_CLOSE_NOTIFY When sever disconnects the connnction gracefully. ( in my case server always disconnncts the connection) . My client and server are running fine without any problem ,   But in case of nginx proxy ssl close notifiy is not received by client.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution so copying it here.

This was happening because the connection was closed by server forcibly by server before client receives SSL_CLOSE_NOTIFY. This was happening because proxy_read_timeout and client_body_timeout was missing from nginx.conf.